# I can't understand the answer key for this exercise

Tags: grammar

The question requires you to choose one correct answer (see below) to fill in the parentheses (between 友達に and と）

> 駅前にできた喫茶店はコーヒーが20種類以上あるそうだ。友達に( )と誘われたので、今度一緒に行くことにした。

it provides four choices as follows:

> A.行ってみないか
> B.   行ったらいい
> C.   行っただろう
> D.  行ってみて

I think A and D are both correct and natural, but the correct answer is A, So why A instead of D?

Answer (score 3):

行ってみて (D) is a suggestion that the listener go (and see). The speaker is not going with them.

行ってみないか (A) could mean either that (*why don’t you go?*) or a suggestion that they go together (*why don’t we go?*).

Meanwhile, the verb 誘う is used to invite the listener to do something with the speaker, and also the sentence explicitly says they are going to go together.

This is why only A is correct and D is incorrect.

Comment: why D has that implication? I can't get that connotation that "The speaker is not going with them" from the sentence, I thought that 行ってみて is contraction of  行ってみてください、so when you filled the sentence with D,that mean "I was invited by my friend who required me to go the cafe".  If you can give more explanation, I wil thank you very much.

Comment: @CN.hitori - 行って or 行ってください is a request to the listener. 行ってみて or 行ってみてください is basically the same in this regard. The agent of 行く is the listener, not the speaker. It’s just that the subsidiary みる makes it a suggestion. The agent of the main verb 行く remains unchanged.